# I want to know what a particular xslt code does

Tags: xml, function, xslt

```
<xsl:variable name="DateNextDay">
    <xsl:value-of select="substring(ut:addDay(concat(./cell[@cnt=$cntTimeTo]/text(),'T00:00:00Z'),3,3,1),1,10)"/>
</xsl:variable>
```

I have the following code but I want to know what ut:addDay does and what the conditions 3,3,1 mean

Comment: `addDay` is not a native XSLT (or XPath) function. The `ut:` prefix indicates it is an extension function, so you will need to find out what the actual extension is and check the relevant documentation. (There should be a declaration of the form `xmlns:ut="..."` which may point you in the right direction).

Comment: <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" exclude-result-prefixes="ut" xmlns:ut="com.ecg.mts.com.utils.XSLTUtils"> this is the declaration of the form but i have no idea where to go from here what would you suggest?

Comment: That "namespace" only yields 5 results when I type it into Google, and none of those results are an exact match. So perhaps it is an "in-house" extension function? Where did you get hold of the XSLT you are looking at? If you were told to work on it as part of your job, you may need to ask around to see if anyone else can help.

Comment: An alternative approach, if you can't find anyone who can help, is to create a very simple stylesheet consisting of just `<xsl:value-of select="ut:addDay('2018-11-08T00:00:00Z'),3,3,1)"/>` and then try adjusting each parameter to see what outcome it has, and try to deduce what they do that way.